# Solutions for BNode in Sesame

Tags: java, rdf, sesame, blank-nodes, openrdf

Is there any solution for processing BNODE in Sesame?
for example:

```
if(! (statement.getObject() instanceof BNode))
        tempModel.remove(statement);
```

if we have an RDF like { s p1 _:a, _:a p2 "value"), therefore even after removing the statement, the second triple will stay in the model. Isn't there any provided solution to handle BNode s in Sesame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
tempModel.remove(statement); // remove the first statement
if (statement.getObject() instanceof BNode) {
      // remove the second statement
      tempModel.remove((BNode)statement.getObject(), null, null);
}
```

That will take care of it in most simple cases.

However, if the BNode is the start of an RDF Collection (that is, modeled using a lot of `rdf:first` and `rdf:rest` properties, and a lot of blank nodes), you will need something a bit more clever than this, as in this case the object of the second statement can *itself* also be blank node again.

In the current Sesame release you will need to do some manual recursive  looping to get this right.

However a [utility function to more easily handle RDF Collections](https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-860) is about to be released in Sesame 4.1.0. If you can't wait until official release you can [peek at its source code](https://bitbucket.org/openrdf/sesame/src/master/core/model/src/main/java/org/openrdf/model/util/RDFCollections.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) and just copy what it does to get your own custom utility functions for this.